# SoapUI - create new request with ServiceEndpoint credentials (password and username)

Tags: soap, request, soapui

I am trying to create new soap request in SoapUI which copies the password username and endpoint from the service endpoint.

It uses the endpoint, but not the username and password.

Does anybody know how to do this?

(I don't want to clone)!

Answer (score 0):

1. Under your endpoint find the method you want, right-click on that and select New request.
2. Name it whatever you want.
3. The Request editor will open allowing you to edit it anyway you want - enter your username and password, and anything else.
4. Close the editor.
5. Find the Request you just created under the endpoint method, right-click on that and select Add to TestCase. Follow the prompts.
6. Once the step is added to a test case, it should look exactly like what you did in #3 above. You are still able to further edit the individual test step - meaning the Request you created in #3 above is in no way linked to the individual test step(s).